# How to send large (10,000+) number of emails via Php/MySQL?

Tags: php

Currently i have a client that wants to send numerous amounts of emails (10,000+) to their clients.. How is this possible?? Any help or advise would be appreciated..

Thanks :)

Comment: one at a time? i mean what are you asking us?

Comment: Care to be more specific? Are you asking what to do so you don't get blacklisted as spam? Or are you wanting to know how to implement the code?

Comment: if you don't know what your doing, consider one of the many companies that do this like mailchimp et al

Comment: yeah, one at a time.. how is this possible? everytime i try to send a large amount of email, the server would timeout..

Comment: Using one of the BILLION email marketing services

Comment: your not doing much to help us help you.

Comment: @dagon: i'm very sorry for asking this non-detailed question, what i want to do is send email to a group of contacts that ranges from 1000 and above.. everytime i try to send numerous amounts of email, the server timesout.. how can avoid this timeouts?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Mail Queue, look at for mail queues at PEAR packages, although mail servers limit how many mails you can send per hour/minute/day.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your problem is that the script is timing out after a certain amount of time.
Couple of things you can do:

1. Look at [max_execution_time in your php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) and boost it.
2. Run your script from CLI, as CLI scripts are not affected by max_execution_time
3. Use a Mail Queue as GeoPhoenix suggests.
4. Split the set into batches and reload (or ajax) the page with a batch itterator.

Comment: yeah, this is exactly the problem that i am encountering.. uhhmm.. how can i run my script from CLI? i haven't tried that CLI stuff before..  I'm really sorry for asking this not detailed question.

Comment: You can run a PHP script from the command line (which uses the CLI version of PHP) using the `php script.php` command. This isn't very useful if your mailer is part of a website and acts on user interaction, but is your best option if sending the mails is your script's only goal.

Comment: can you be more detailed with regards to what CLI is because im not that familiar with it.. I'll give you an insight of what i want to do.. I have a form, the form contains a textarea where you can right your mail and checkboxes that contains groupnames of contact, each group name consist of at least 10000 members.. once i fill up my textarea and select a group.. i want to send the message to the members of the group that i selected..